# why does node-sodium package is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, libsodium, sodium

Here I'm using node for making a discord bot, but there is a problem in the packages I think
Also, sodium is not found in the node_modules directory (folder)
tried many ways but nothing work :(

```
Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> npm install

> sodium@3.0.2 preinstall /home/runner/test/node_modules/sodium
> node install.js --preinstall

Static libsodium was not found at /home/runner/test/node_modules/sodium/deps/build/lib/libsodium so compiling libsodium from source.
libtool is required, but wasn't found on this system
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'libsodium' failed
make: *** [libsodium] Error 1
/home/runner/bgrb/node_modules/sodium/install.js:293
            throw new Error(cmdLine + ' exited with code ' + code);
            ^

Error: make libsodium exited with code 2
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/test/node_modules/sodium/install.js:293:19)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
npm WARN discord.js@11.6.4 requires a peer of @discordjs/uws@^10.149.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sodium@3.0.2 preinstall: `node install.js --preinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sodium@3.0.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-03-07T10_42_18_435Z-debug.log
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using some form of linux distro. (correct me if im wrong.)

---

by the looks of it you're missing `libtool`

try running `apt-get install libtool` in your terminal. (or install with whatever package manager you're using!)

---

if you're not using linux, or you are still having trouble please feel free to respond to this post.